# Can I define OR operator in CSS selectors?

Tags: css, css-selectors

Consider this:

```
p + a, i + a { // some property }
```

Now I'm trying to do something like this:

```
(p | i) + a { // some property }
```

Is there anything similar this ^?

Comment: Not at the moment.

Comment: If `i` and `p` had the same class name, then you could probably use the class name instead.